# .hg folder not in working directory when using Teamcity and Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, teamcity

I try to run following command line build step in my Teamcity configuration to get latest tag to text file:

```
hg log -r tip --template {latesttag} > version.txt
```

Command will end up with error:
abort: no repository found in 'D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\ec2a0c1f516aab26' (.hg not found)!

.hg folder is missing from working directory. It looks like Teamcity gets the files in repository so that .hg folder newer comes to working directory.

When I clone repository manually using "hg clone" the .hg folder is included and I can run "hg log" command without problems.

How can I get .hg folder to be included in working directory using Teamcity?

*Teamcity version is 9.1.1*

Comment: Just wondering if there is some setting in (Teamcity) Mercurial config that can be used for this?  
VCS root configuration has setting "Mercurial config" and I am looking for if anything can be done that way.
Also I have tried to find out what hg command Teamcity is executing when doing check out but I haven't been able to get them visible at build log.

Answer (score 4):

**Agent-side checkout** must be [selected](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/VCS+Checkout+Mode) on **Version Control Settings** page to get the ability to access version control-specific directories and communicate with the repository from the build.